# How often do I need to backup my MBR?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mbr

If the partitions on a drive don't change, do I need to backup that disk's MBR if only the *data* changes?

And if so, how often?

Comment: @Mokubai, a corrupt MBR, which I've had happen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time the MBR will change is when you change the partitions or install a boot loader.

So this is usually done as a one-shot whenever it's needed.